# Notation confusion - sigma algebra generated by multiple sigma algebras.

Tags: measure-theory, notation

This is a quick one. Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ be probabilistc space. Let  $\mathcal{F_1}, \mathcal{F_2}, \mathcal{F_3}, ...$ be $\sigma$-algebras such that $\mathcal{F_i} \subset \mathcal{F}$ for all $i$. Question: What is ment by notation $\sigma (\mathcal{F}_n, \mathcal{F}_{n+1}, ..) $? Is it the same as $$\sigma (\bigcup_{k=n}^{\infty} \mathcal{F}_k )$$
or maybe $$\sigma(\bigcap_{k=n}^{\infty} \mathcal{F}_k )$$
My textbook omitts the definition, and I can't  find it's meaning anywhere online. Forgive me if it's a dumb question.

Comment: What textbook are you getting the notation from? I have seen $\sigma$ used to denote "the $\sigma$-algebra generated by...", which in your case would mean the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing the $\mathcal{F}_n$ (and that may not be all of $\mathcal{F}$).

Comment: Yes, it means of "σ-algebra generated by...". In context of your comment then,  $\sigma (\mathcal{F}_n, \mathcal{F}_{n+1}, ..) $ =  $\sigma (\bigcup_{k=n}^{\infty} \mathcal{F}_k )$ is correct, right?

Comment: I believe that is correct, yes